# Automate Text Import in Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write an Excel macro using VBA to automate importing CSV text into a spreadsheet but I've never done it before.  I need to make sure that the Text Import Wizard that comes up is run through the same way each time.  The steps I need to take are:

1. Open a file, using an open file dialog
2. Set type to Delimited
3. Set Delimiter to comma
4. Set all columns to be imported as Text
5. Auto fit all columns

I can't seem to wade through the documentation that shows how to do these things like open files.  Even being able to start there would be helpful.

Comment: You might want to use PowerShell to automate GUI instead - e.g. do all the work outside of Excel.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I ended up making some tweaks to the function before putting it into use.

```
Public Sub OpenCsv()
    ' I don't expect any more columns than 256 in my environment, so I can 
    ' just fill this array and call it done.
    Dim columnFormats(0 To 255) As Integer
    For i = 0 To 255
        columnFormats(i) = xlTextFormat
    Next i

    Dim filename As Variant
    filename = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files (*.*),*.*", 1, "Open", "", False)
    ' If user clicks Cancel, stop.
    If (filename = False) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Application.Workbooks.Add
    Set ws = Excel.ActiveSheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
    Sheets("Sheet3").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


    With ws.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & filename, ws.Cells(1, 1))
        .FieldNames = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        ''// This array will need as many entries as there will be columns:
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = columnFormats
        .Refresh
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks to the above guys for getting me going.

Comment: Normally you should mark someone else's answer as accepted if they got you on the right track, even if it wasn't exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 5):

The code below will allow a user to browse for a csv file.
It will then :

- Open the selected file, treating the data as text
- Resize the columns
- Move the data into the workbook from which the code is run.

The .opentext code needs to be updated depending on the number of columns in the source data.

```
Sub ImportCSV()

Dim vPath As Variant
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = Excel.ActiveSheet

vPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV (Comma Delimited) (*.csv),*.csv" _
, 1, "Select a file", , False)
''//Show the file open dialog to allow user to select a CSV file

If vPath = False Then Exit Sub
''//Exit macro if no file selected

Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=vPath, Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1 _
    , DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Comma:=True _
    , FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, xlTextFormat), Array(2, xlTextFormat), _
    Array(3, xlTextFormat))
''//The fieldinfo array needs to be extended to match your number of columns

Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
''//Resize the columns

Sheets(1).Move Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
''//Move the data into the Workbook

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Public Sub Example()
    Const csPath As String = "C:\Test\Example.csv"
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = Excel.ActiveSheet
    With ws.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & csPath, ws.Cells(1, 1))
        .FieldNames = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        ''// This array will need as many entries as there will be columns:
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat)
        .Refresh
    End With
End Sub
```