# Difficulty in finding end of row in VB Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am reading in information from a .txt file, This text file has 2 row and 6 column; each element is separated by space or tab. I have the data to read all the strings but I find difficult in putting the data to the cells. How can I find end of first Row.

Text File:

```
$SUBCASE       1                             1
$DISP          0     509       5       1     2
```

Below is the complete code, I'm getting only the first character string and rest not...

```
Private Sub PCH_Click()
Dim arTemp() As Variant
Dim lRet As String
Dim sVal As String
Dim Row As Long
Dim Col As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
'Default method Uses Open Dialog To Show the Files
lRet = Application.GetOpenFilename("PCH files (*.pch), *.*")
'Reads the file into characters
sVal = OpenTextFileToString2(lRet)
Dim tmp As Variant
    tmp = SplitMultiDelims(sVal, ",;$ ", True)   ' Place the 2nd argument with the list of delimiter you need to use
    Row = 0
    For i = LBound(tmp, 1) To UBound(tmp, 1)
        Row = Row + 1
        Col = 1
        While Not vbNewLine = ""
            ws.Cells(Row, Col) = tmp(i)  'output on the first column
            MsgBox (tmp(i))
            Col = Col + 1
        Wend
    Next i
End Sub
Function OpenTextFileToString2(ByVal strFile As String) As String
' RB Smissaert - Author
Dim hFile As Long
hFile = FreeFile
Open strFile For Input As #hFile
OpenTextFileToString2 = Input$(LOF(hFile), hFile)
Close #hFile
End Function
Function SplitMultiDelims(ByRef Text As String, ByRef DelimChars As String, _
        Optional ByVal IgnoreConsecutiveDelimiters As Boolean = False, _
        Optional ByVal Limit As Long = -1) As String()
    Dim ElemStart As Long, N As Long, M As Long, Elements As Long
    Dim lDelims As Long, lText As Long
    Dim Arr() As String

    lText = Len(Text)
    lDelims = Len(DelimChars)
    If lDelims = 0 Or lText = 0 Or Limit = 1 Then
        ReDim Arr(0 To 0)
        Arr(0) = Text
        SplitMultiDelims = Arr
        Exit Function
    End If
    ReDim Arr(0 To IIf(Limit = -1, lText - 1, Limit))

    Elements = 0: ElemStart = 1
    For N = 1 To lText
        If InStr(DelimChars, Mid(Text, N, 1)) Then
            Arr(Elements) = Mid(Text, ElemStart, N - ElemStart)
            If IgnoreConsecutiveDelimiters Then
                If Len(Arr(Elements)) > 0 Then Elements = Elements + 1
            Else
                Elements = Elements + 1
            End If
            ElemStart = N + 1
            If Elements + 1 = Limit Then Exit For
        End If
    Next N
    'Get the last token terminated by the end of the string into the array
    If ElemStart <= lText Then Arr(Elements) = Mid(Text, ElemStart)
    'Since the end of string counts as the terminating delimiter, if the last character
    'was also a delimiter, we treat the two as consecutive, and so ignore the last elemnent
    If IgnoreConsecutiveDelimiters Then If Len(Arr(Elements)) = 0 Then Elements = Elements - 1
    ReDim Preserve Arr(0 To Elements) 'Chop off unused array elements
    SplitMultiDelims = Arr
End Function
```

Comment: what is `EOF(l0)`?  You should just be able to check for a line ending. try While not vbNewLine

Comment: I tried to use "While Not vbNewLine" but still I have error...

Comment: Here is my complete code:

Comment: Can't you just import the text file into Excel using built in VBA functions, like suggested at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285552/automate-text-import-in-excel-2007)?

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file row by row with following code

```
Sub IOTest()
    Dim fnum, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim line    As String
    Dim lines   As Variant

    Dim regEx   As Object
    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With regEx
        .Pattern = "\s{1}"  'only one whitespace
        .Global = True      'find all occurrences
    End With

    fnum = FreeFile()
    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\IO_Test.txt" For Input As #fnum

    Do Until EOF(fnum)      'until End of file
        i = i + 1
        Input #fnum, line   'load row into line

        'First replace found sole whitespaces with ","
        'Then split on the ","s
        lines = Split(regEx.Replace(line, ","), ",")
        For j = LBound(lines) To UBound(lines)
            Cells(i, j + 1) = lines(j)
        Next j
    Loop
    Close #fnum
End Sub
```

I tested this with the strings

```
"$SUBCASE" & vbTab & "1" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "1"
"$DISP" & vbTab & "0" & vbTab & "509" & vbTab & "5" & vbTab & "1" & vbTab & "2"
```

And it only works if you have one whitespace(eg. space, tab,...) separating the data. If you have more than one whitespace between the data it gets trickier. But if you can provide an example on how the data is separated I can take a look at it.

I hope it helps, let me know either way ;)