# Zip code is dropping leading zero when displayed on excel. Export to excel from vb.net XML to XSLT transform

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt, export, export-to-excel

I am exporting data from vb.net to excel and it is dropping the leading zero when its displayed on excel. How can I avoid the dropping of leading zero? I read the solution of adding a single quote but it makes my excel sheet column ugly. Also users will complain if they see a single quote on zip code field.
  vb.net code

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment)
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        Response.Charset = ""
```

the stored procedure outputs XML and it is transformed by XSLT before it is displayed on EXCEL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <HTML>
      <HEAD>
        <STYLE type="text/css"> TABLE{table-layout: automatic; width:100%} .tblHeader{background-color:RGB(192,192,192);font-weight:bold} .row1{background-color:RGB(204,204,255)} .row2{background-color:RGB(153,204,255)} </STYLE>
      </HEAD>
      <BODY>
        <TABLE border="1">

          <THEAD>
            <tr class="tblHeader">
              <xsl:for-each select="*/*[1]/*">
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </td>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
          </THEAD>

          <TBODY>
            <xsl:for-each select="ClientArray/Client">
              <TR>

                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                  <TD>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </TD>
                </xsl:for-each>

              </TR>
            </xsl:for-each>

          </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
      </BODY>
    </HTML>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help me with a solution other than adding a single quote or manipulating excel sheet with column formatter (general/numbers ) etc. I don't want user to make any changes on excel to get the display properly
   when the excel is displayed from web page it should be all set with proper formatting. also we have no control over client excel software

Comment: It's because it's a number field and Excel strips leading zeros from them. You'll have to store it as text, but other than using the leading ' I'm not sure how you'd do that.

Comment: well, the zip code is a string field in my database and is exported as a string to excel. i'm still wondering

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137359/excel-csv-number-cell-format

Answer (score 1):

Number cells in Excel are automatically stripped of leading zeros. In order to preserve the preceeding zeros, you'll have to set the cell's data to text [which is achieved by adding an apostrophe to the zip code].

I don't use Excel Interop that much so I can't tell you exactly how to set the cell's data type to text but I can assure you that that's the way to fix your problems.

Comment: well, the zip code is a string field in my database and is exported as a string to excel. i'm still wondering. 
  I don't use excel interop either. Its just a response.contenttype and not an excel interop API. Also we cannot control the properties of excel instance at client. please help

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<TD style="mso-number-format:\@;">
```

It will preserve the `Leading zeros`.

Comment: Enggr - I know it is too late, just wanted to update you. Have you tried the above code?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem when exporting to Excel via PHP. I found that prepending an equals sign and surrounding the zip with double-quotes caused Excel to preserve the leading zero.

I don't know vb.net, but in PHP that would look like this:

```
echo '="' . $the_zip_code . '"';
```

Answer (score 0):

how about formatting the number through xsl?
look at http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_formatnumber.asp

Answer (score -2):

Go to the cell you are working on. Right click, Click on format cells, and test. Type in your number with the leading zeros, it will stay.

Comment: Actually it won't and this does not address the question