# format of number on downloading in csv format

Tags: php

Following code returns hours for given seconds, which is working.

```
<?php

$hrs = seconds_to_dezi(278280);
echo $hrs;
$filename = "test";
header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");

function seconds_to_dezi($s) {
    $n = false;
    if ($s < 0) {
        $n = true;
        $s = -$s;
    }
    $h = round($s / 3600,2);
    $h = number_format($h,2, ',', ' ');
    $h = str_replace(".",",",$h);


    if ($n == true) {
        return ("-" . $h);
    } else {
        return ($h);
    }
}

?>
```

Actual output in excel:- 77,3

Expected output is:- 77,30

i.e on downloading values in csv format, the trailing zero after decimal is truncated. I want to have that zero in excel.

Comment: Found a duplicate that has some good answers:  [Excel CSV - Number cell format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137359/excel-csv-number-cell-format)

Comment: Hi pekka, i have checked the possible answers in other question. But none of them helped me. If i force the number as string 7.75 is interpreted as jul 75 in excel 2007.So post me if there any alternate solutions

Comment: I don't think there are any more solutions than what is shown there. I think you'll have to set the column format manually in Excel after importing, or actually write an Excel file in PHP (which however is much, much more complex.)

Answer (score 1):

The function is returning 77,30. The thing is that Excel doesn't show the final 0, but it's there. Open the file with a text editor.

Comment: ...as long as you don't re-save while in Excel!

Comment: Thanku, yes i have checked it and it is the problem only with excel.

Comment: This is not his question. He wants to *see* the zero

Comment: @Pekka He wants to see it, but I think he was also worried it isn't generated properly. So my answer along with the duplicate you posted should fully answer his question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot explicitly set the number of decimals in a CSV file. If you need to show 77,30 you can use ="70,30". It will show up in the file correct, but it will be text then. So you can no longer use it as a number in excel.

Comment: Thanku, if i force to print it as "77,30". I am not able to do math operations in excel. I need to convert it manually back to number:( on converting back to number zeros are again removed.