# Issue in exporting data to CSV

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I am doing export of data from database to Excel. After exporting when opening the csv file, the excel application is autoformating the values in excel.

One my cell contained the value **-A1177**, but it got converted to zero.

Can any one let me know is there any solution to avoid this or switch off this autoformat in excel.

thanks.

Comment: This is an excel issue. Not an c# one. Your doing the perfect job in porting to excel. 

May be try to format the excel column to just string type tingy. I forgot exactly what type

Comment: You could open Excel without clicking the csv-file. Click `Data/Get External Data/From Text/Choose the csv-file`. Then you can ensure that all columns will be in the correct format(`text` when in doubt). http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-import-wizard-HP010102244.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it, is to simply wrap the value in quotes, e.g. `asdasd,"-A1177",11/03/1984` in your CSV file.  You can also change the format of the column to `Text'.

Otherwise, check out this excellent [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137359/excel-csv-number-cell-format) and [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137359/excel-csv-number-cell-format/142073#142073)

Comment: @Bhaskar: you have to write `="-A1177"`. Don't forget the `=` or it wont work.

Comment: I tried this it worked but the double quotes is visible too. I dont want that too be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Change column Data Format when importing the text change it to Text

Answer (score 0):

Insert a `'` at the start of any formula in `Excel` and it will be considered a `string`.

So if possible, check when generating the CSV file if the first char in a given field can be understood as an Excel formula "opener" (off my mind `{=, -, +}`) and prepend a `'`.

You can do it for every field, but its only strictly necessary if the text can be misunderstood as a formula.