# Scripting in Windows to create excel sheets

Tags: windows, excel, scripting, windows-scripting

I have a txt file that contains data which I need to input to Excel.

The problem is I have several of those files and I want to create an excel file for each. So I was thinking of scripting.
Can anyone point me to how to start atleast the tool needed and language to use

Thanks

**EDIT**: turns out naming the extension .csv can directly open it in excel. Now looking on how to open .csv , change format to autofit width and then save to excel

Comment: Did you want to save the txt files as (1) individual files or (2) inside one workbook as either (a)  a combined file on one sheet (b) one sheet for each text file

Comment: @brettdj I want each txt file as individual file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just write CSV files... They open on Excel and require no effort.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: I am writing a CSV file but I'll have to go to excel and import from text then save with the file name...It's an easy job to do once, but I want it many times. So was checking if I can automate it

Comment: Chip Pearson has code and instruction posted on how to loop through directories http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/QuickTree.aspx

Comment: CSV files have some problems to be aware of. The most common is that it will translate numeric-looking strings into numbers and drop leading zeros. There is no way to turn this off except via the manual import method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137359/excel-csv-number-cell-format also.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. I have happen to enjoy php a lot for this type of task, but most any other scripting language is capable of this. Ie: Python, Ruby .. and many more.

PHP comes with [many built-in functions for CSV](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). It also [runs fine on windows](http://windows.php.net/), is cross-platform if you ever need to port on a 'nux environnement.  The language is quite easy to learn, there are tons and tons of tutorials out there for most anything you want to script.

To get started, if you want to crack the ice there is a very simple but working example [here](http://mattiasgeniar.be/2008/06/04/creating-excel-files-through-php/), with links to more php/excel ressources.  OF course, if you take this path, there are many many more examples  waiting for you on google.

Hope that helps, good-luck!

Comment: Seems unnecessary to go outside of Excel to script this when Excel's VBA is more than sufficient to accomplish it.

Comment: Yes! Obviously, now that you mention it. Being a Linux developper, I have not used Office for the past 10 years. I still would slap this up in php, but to be fair the builtin scripting engine would probably do just as well, minus the portability and flexibility.

Comment: You linux guys, there's a joke about a hammer and a nail in there somewhere..... ;)

Comment: Yeah. +1'ed all of you! *I should have known* mentionning PHP in a Windows thread would make me an easy target! Totally worth the laugh.