# Excel is removing 00 from start of cell

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel CSV - Number cell format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137359/excel-csv-number-cell-format)

I have written a C# .net windows application that writes data to a csv file, one of the fields is an invoice number which start with "`00`" i.e. `00144544`. I have checked the csv and it is in the correct format.

Is there anything I can do either in my export or in excel to prevent this?

Comment: Excel "helps" you format data when it opens a CSV file, such as detecting when you might be using a date. As long as the data is correct in the CSV file, do you actually need it viewable in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the value in quotes so excel recognizes it as a string.
for example:

```
"00144544"
```

Comment: The "cleanest" solution, as the CSV file is still readable.

Comment: I agree but @Matt Burlands is good if you still want excel to treat the text as a number and not a string.

Comment: This doesn't work (at least in Excel 2007). The quotes are just used to allow commas to be embedded in the text but the value is still being interpreted as a number.

Comment: @DaveHogan: Actually, I think Excel still treats it as a string. Your solution is probably more robust and better from a CSV "standards" (what there are of them) stand point. My solution works, in Excel, but I couldn't guarantee that it'll work anywhere else.

Comment: hum... you're right. I just tested both double quotes and a single starting quote and they don't work in 2010? Have MS changed something?

Comment: @DaveHogan: Yeah, I just tried it and found the same thing.

Comment: I just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137359 which shows how close you were: `="00144544"` will do it.

Comment: the equals sign did it, thanks @DoMax

Answer (score 1):

The solution as @DocMax stated is to create your csv and put a "=" sign before your value so when writing a line you can do:

```
this._exportText.Append("=" + "\"" + (row.Index != null ? row.Index.ToString() : "").Trim() + "\",");
```

Without the "=" it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is a pain for doing this. One way around it is to prefix your number with a '. This will make Excel treat it as a string instead of automatically converting it to a number and lopping off your leading zeros.

Comment: When I tried this by creating a CSV file with `a,'00034` and opening it in Excel 2007, the `'` is shown in the column.

Comment: @DocMax: Huh, I just tried it in 2010 and you are right. The `'` does appear. I thought an earlier version, at least, hid it. Maybe I'm misremembering. At least it does preserve the leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

When you import the data into Excel, tell it (in the import wizard) to consider the column as text rather than auto-detecting the column type.

Comment: @NeilKnight: The OP says C# is writing the CSV, not necessarily that it is being used to do the import.

Comment: I am writing it to a csv so cannot set the column settings

Comment: @CR41G14: My solution has to be done when you open the CSV in Excel (which is cleary sub-optimal). Check out the SO question I linked in a comment on your question for the best approach (which is very close to DaveHogan's).

Comment: you comment was the solution therefore +1

Answer (score 0):

You can put a ' character at the front or, more usefully, set the column number format to `00000000`

To do that, select the column header (or cells), click on the number format dropdown, choose 'more number formats', then custom and then type in your format.