# fprintf in bold/emphazied or highlighted cells mfc c++

Tags: c++, mfc, printf

A simple question about fprintf function.

I made a a program that reads lines from a text file which hold values such as

```
INFO 2013-12-17 11:59:24,549 Thread-3 2032 CommonMMC.request_hardware_state() - Common 1 State = PASS (warn=False,fail=False)
INFO 2013-12-17 11:59:25,081 Thread-3 2032 CommonMMC.request_hardware_state() - Common 1 State = PASS (warn=False,fail=False)
INFO 2013-12-17 11:59:25,549 Thread-3 2032 CommonMMC.request_hardware_state() - Common 1 State = WARN (warn=False,fail=False)
INFO 2013-12-17 11:59:26,081 Thread-3 2032 CommonMMC.request_hardware_state() - Common 1 State = FAIL (warn=False,fail=False)
```

It then checks for the state change in each line and prints it out respectively onto a .csv file. The .csv file should look like this

```
XCBU02   PM671   17-DEC-2013     10:30:56    Common 2    State   WARNING

XCBU02   PM671   17-DEC-2013     10:30:56    Common 2    State   PASS
```

It is all working fine and it prints out correctly.

the printf function is as such :-

```
fprintf(readCSV_fp, "%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %d, %s, %s", XCBU, Test_ID, Date, Time, Comm, Num, State, State_Change);
```

all the Variables are defined as CStrings except for Num which is an int.

My question is, is there a way to print out State_Change onto the .csv file but have it **BOLD** or *Emphasized* or even have the cell that it is being printed on in the .csv file to be highlighted?

If yes, how do I manage it? and if its no, is there any other method where I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.CSV file format is a simple text file and it does not support any formatting.

There are many other text formats that allow setting font, background/foreground color, etc.

One of them is Excel Open XML. I believe it will work with Microsoft Excel only... Initial question was mentioning MFC. I think mentioning Excel in the answer is appropriate.

Comment: Is Open XML easy to use? My go-to format has been SYLK. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/137473/5987

Comment: They have a .NET library that has reasonable interface. I used it myself and it works fine. It provides only C# interface. You can research, maybe something is available for C++ also. You can also write small C# samples of what you want and look at what is generated. After that your can generate the same stuffs with C++.