# How to pragmatically set the excel number format to text for a csv file?

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I am wring a csv file with some program.

I am facing a issue when I open it in the excel file and for some column if it exceeds the value more than 256 it automatically truncate it.

I learnt that by default the excel has number format TO `'GENERAL'` if I could set it to `'TEXT'` then it wouldn't truncate any part.

So is there  any programmatic way which can set the number format from `GENERAL` to `TEXT`.

Comment: I think you have a different problem, Excel can certainly read CSV files with values exceeding 256 in them. Please show us a few lines of your CSV file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137359/excel-csv-number-cell-format

Comment: Not sure how this relates to C#.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: you mean code you want to see. How i am doing it in csv file.

Comment: I mean you should click `edit` underneath your question and paste in 2-3 lines of your actual CSV that Excel will not import correctly.

Comment: Ben robinson: i understand csv files are independent of excel or .txt but it does truncate in excel so i want not it to truncate and want to fix it in csv file itself.

Comment: Oh!!!! You don't mean the VALUE exceeds 256 - you mean the LENGTH of a text string exceeds 256 characters!!! Don't you?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: yes, I mean the same..can we achieve it with C# code.

Answer (score 0):

[csv](/questions/tagged/csv) is a plain text format.  You can't embed meta-data such as column handling into that file format.

If you don't want [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) to truncate the column, then you'll need to truncate it yourself when you write out the [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) file:

```
 var csvFileBuffer = new StringBuilder();

 var columns = new List<string>();

 csvFileBuffer.AppendLine(
     string.Join(
         ",",
         columns.Select(s => 
              //truncate column header (change logic as appropriate)
              s.Substring(0, 255))));
```

That said, there may be an option you can set in [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) which will change the default column type for a csv file.  However, that would be a question for [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com)

The other option is to write out to a native excel file format, such as `xlsx`.  There are a number of tools you can use to this, such as the [Open Xml Sdk](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2010/06/22/writing-large-excel-files-with-the-open-xml-sdk.aspx).

Comment: No, by default excel truncating the text ahead of 255 i want not it to truncate. I want all data .

Comment: You wont be able to achieve that by adding a magic string to a `.csv' file