# write long integer to csv

Tags: c#, excel, csv, c#-3.0

I need to write some long integer to csv file with C# (vs2010), for example, the number is 33333333333333333, but when I open the csv file with excel, what I see is like this: 3.33333E+16, I don't want this effect, I just want to see the number in text format when open it in Excel.
my code is like below:

```
var csv = new StringBuilder();
var filePath = "c:\\zzx\\test.csv";

long a = 222222222222222222L;
long b = 33333333333333333L;

var newLine = string.Format("'{0},\"{1}\"", a, b);
csv.AppendLine(newLine);

File.WriteAllText(filePath, csv.ToString());
```

can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: You cannot control formatting in a CSV, since it's just a plain-text file.  You could prepend your number with a single-quote, but then it will be treated as text in Excel.

Comment: You might find it instructive to paste that value (17 `3`s) into a cell in Excel, and see what value Excel actually ends up holding...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel CSV - Number cell format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137359/excel-csv-number-cell-format)