# Python 3 Pandas write to CSV format column as string

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas, formatting

having an issue with handling oddly formatted excel data and writing to CSV in a string format.  In my sample data, the excel table I am importing has a column ('Item_Number') and the odd data in the cell looks like: ="0001", ="00201", 2002AA, 1003B.

When I try to output to csv, the results look like: 1, 201, 2002AA, 1003B.
When I try to output to excel, the results are correct: 0001, 00201, 2002AA, 1003B.

All of the dtypes are objects.  Am I missing a parameter in my .to_csv() command?

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename,sheetname='Sheet1', converters= {'Item_Number':str})
df.to_csv('Test_csv.csv')
df.to_excel('Test_excel.xlsx')
```

Tried different iterations of replacing the "=" and " " " but no response.

```
df.Item_Number.str.replace('=','')
```

Currently using the excel output but curious if there is a way to preserve string formatting in CSV.  Thanks :)

Comment: For me it works perfect. How do you test your file? By `df = pd.read_csv('Test_csv.csv')` or by text editor?

Comment: I was opening it in excel as a csv.  Will test again.

Comment: Was opening it in excel as a csv.
Tried:
     df = pd.Series([="0001", ="00201", 2002AA, 1003B]).astype(str)
but that format won't run.  It looks like the read.excel() function can interpret ="0001"  from an excel spreadsheet and export correctly, but not to csv.  To be clear, ="0001" is in the cell.

Comment: Further research - This may be an excel issue, not a Python Pandas issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137359/excel-csv-number-cell-format

Answer (score 3):

Opening an excel spreadsheet with Python 3 Pandas that has data that looks like ="0001" will go to the dataframe correctly.  CSV will turn it back to "1".  Keeping the same format to CSV is apparently a known issue (from my comment above).  To keep the formatting I have to add  =" "  back into the data like this:

```
df['Item_Number'] = '="' + df['Item_Number'] + '"'
```

Not sure if there is a cleaner version to that will have an Excel opened CSV file show 0001 without the quotes and equals sign.