# strings converted to floats in a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

When I write a certain fraction in a csv file it gets automatically calculated whereas my requirement is to keep it as it is.

This is my try:

```
import csv

ft = "-1/-1.5" #or -1/-1.5 (removing the quotes)
print(ft)

with open("outputfile.csv","w",newline="") as infile:
    writer = csv.writer(infile)
    writer.writerow([ft])
```

Console prints it when in quotes:

```
-1/-1.5
```

However, when I write them same in a csv file it becomes like the following no matter when I try using quotes or without quotes.

```
0.666666667
```

***How can I write the same in a csv file like `-1/-1.5`?***

See the image below (this is what I'm getting right now):

[image]

If i try use a `'` in a cell and then write the value, the output serves the purpose. Can I not do it programmatically?

[image]

Comment: looks like M$ Excel is interpreting the cell converting the fraction to a decimal value. But if you open `outputfile.csv` in a plain text viewer (i.e. Notepad) you should see the `csv` still contains the string `1/-1.5`. I think Excel cell formatting can be changed: see the advice in this post https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/909497-how-stop-excel-automatically-converting-fractions-decimals.html, "You could format the cells as 'general'."

Comment: or you could consider using [xlwt](http://www.python-excel.org/) module and set the cell formatting for you; see [Format csv cells as text with python](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/909497-how-stop-excel-automatically-converting-fractions-decimals.html)

Comment: Ain't there any option to do the same on the fly without using any predefined format or post processing?

Comment: this is not a python problem, it's how Microsoft Excel interprets the cell data in csv files. Look at this answer's advice: [Excel CSV - Number cell format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137359/excel-csv-number-cell-format)

Comment: Check out the update. We perhaps do it using python.

Comment: Yes, that looks like a good solution. Put it in an answer

Comment: I found it working (to do the same manually) but cant find any idea to do that using python @davedwards.

Comment: sure, try `writer.writerow("'%s" % ft)`

Comment: It `writer.writerow([f"'{ft}"])` did the trick as well. However, if you post it as an answer I'm ready to accept it. If anyone encounters similar issues might get help.

Comment: Okay yes sure, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As OP [mentioned in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806264/strings-converted-to-floats-in-a-csv-file?noredirect=1#comment90568481_51806264) use:

`writer.writerow([f"'{ft}"])`

will add formatting to the `csv` output file so M$ Excel will display the string values in string `ft` retaining their original string format.