# Is it possible to write a text file that MS Excel will open and display numbers with thousand-separators?

Tags: excel

Is it possible to give formatting instructions in a csv-like file? Can I have the numbers in one column formatted as money, for instance? With commas and two digits after the decimal point (even if they're zeroes)?

Comment: "Is it possible to give formatting instructions in a csv-like file". Depends on what you mean by "csv-like". You could of course write your own file specification, but the point of csv files are that they are simple text files just containing the data. Let the application that reads the file worry about what it is going to do with the data. If the numbers in csv file are strings with commas, the application could use those commas in its formatting. I don't think Excel itself would automatically change its default number format in a case like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel CSV - Number cell format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137359/excel-csv-number-cell-format)